# Sql Command Union not working for Colum Type Images

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

Sql Union Command giing this error "Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."
when  i am trying this query

```
Select Img from test_table Where userid = 3 
Union
Select TOP 12 Img from MultiImages
```

Please tell me how to overCome with this problem

Comment: Do you really need `UNION` there? Do you really need to remove duplicate values? If not, `UNION ALL` would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Allot, now it works fine with Union All :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to nvarchar first. You have not mentioned what version of SQL you are using but for SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 (and later) you can use this:

```
SELECT CAST([Img] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM test_table 
WHERE userid = 3 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 12 CAST([Img] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM MultiImages
```

Else if you have SQL 2000 you can not use max so you have to specify how large the varchar would be e.g.

```
SELECT CAST([Img] AS NVARCHAR(4000))
    FROM test_table 
    WHERE userid = 3 
    UNION 
    SELECT TOP 12 CAST([Img] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) 
    FROM MultiImages
```

Comment: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Explicit conversion from data type image to nvarchar(max) is not allowed.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: sql 2008 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.1600.22

Comment: As far as I remember, `image` type is for storing binary data, not text. So, try converting to `varbinary(max)` instead of `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: yes it is selecting now 6 rows, but is have to select 12+ rows 12 from one table and some other from 1st table

Comment: @Avais oh sorry you didnt mention you needed duplicate data so I assumed you use union to remove them

Comment: @TheProvost sorry its my mistake ,any ways Thanks to you for helping me  .